# Is there a connection between the two times 7 cows, ears and years that Yaakov worked for his wives?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, number, vayeitzei, miketz

Is there any connection or relationship between the seven fat & seven lean cows, the seven beautiful and seven parched ears of grain that Pharaoh dreamt and Yosef interpreted, and the seven years that Yaacov worked for each of his wives, Rachel and Leah?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86842/discussion-on-question-by-yaacov-deane-is-there-a-connection-between-the-two-tim).